# How to handle multiline sytem.out.println's in log4j

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, log4j

When i enable the logs for ssl handshake in a spring boot application each system.out.println is logged as a single entry in graylog. I'm looking for a solution in java that keeps the multilines together.

```
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|EF|http-nio-auto-1-exec-5|2023-03-31 10:28:37.444 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:272|Ignore, context unavailable extension: renegotiation_info
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|EF|http-nio-auto-1-exec-5|2023-03-31 10:28:37.445 CEST|ClientHello.java:641|Produced ClientHello handshake message (
"ClientHello": {
  "client version"      : "TLSv1.2",
  "random"              : "19F2B67470FA4E573D50B452679D7F794D527517E",
  "session id"          : "0A68F7268E1A29EA4F1AEC6943453D31C9EA02EEC8",
  "cipher suites"       : "[TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0xC02C), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0xC02B), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256(0xCCA9), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0xC030),
```

Only the javax.net.ssl.... line should be logged as single entry in graylog.

I would like to know if a log4j appender or a PrintStream (that could be assign to System.setOut(...)) already exists where a pattern can be defined which lines should be hold together?
Filebeat would be an option (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/multiline-examples.html) but would prefer a solution that can be configured in the spring boot application. Logstash is not in use.

Answer (score 0):

In order to capture debug messages from [Oracle's SSL implementation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/security/oracle-providers.html#GUID-7093246A-31A3-4304-AC5F-5FB6400405E2) you need:

1. Configure it to use a proper logging API instead of `System.out`,
2. Use a logging layout that allows for multiline messages.

### Redirect SunJSEE debug

Since Java 8, SunJSSE can use a proper logging API if you set the `javax.net.debug` variable to an **empty** string, e.g. with `-Djavax.net.debug=`. The actual logging API depends on the Java version:

- Java 8 uses `java.util.logging`. You'll need [`log4j-jul`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-jul.html) to forward it to the Log4j 2.x API,
- Java 9 and later uses [`System.Logger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/System.Logger.html). You'll need [`log4j-jpl`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-jpl.html) to forward it to the Log4j 2.x API. Alternatively `System.Logger` binds by default to `java.util.logging`.

### Change logging layout

To easily import your SunJSSE logs into Graylog you probably want to use a GELF layout. Your `log4j2-spring.xml` file would look like this:

```xml
<Configuration name="app" status="WARN">
  <Appenders>
    <File name="FILE" fileName="${sys:LOG_FILE}">
      <JsonTemplateLayout eventTemplateUri="classpath:GelfLayout.json"/>
    </File>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="INFO">
      <AppenderRef ref="FILE"/>
    </Root>
    <Logger name="javax.net.ssl" level="DEBUG"/>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

(you need [`log4j-layout-json-template`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/json-template-layout.html) for this).

Alternatively you can use an [RFC5424 layout](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#RFC5424Layout) and escape the new lines:

```xml
<Configuration name="app" status="WARN">
  <Appenders>
    <File name="FILE" fileName="${sys:LOG_FILE}">
      <Rfc5424Layout newLine="true" newLineEscape=" "/>
    </File>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="INFO">
      <AppenderRef ref="FILE"/>
    </Root>
    <Logger name="javax.net.ssl" level="DEBUG"/>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: I struggle with the configuration. I'm using java 17. Only warnings and error are logged and the logs are twice in graylog because they are still logged to system.out as well.

Comment: config looks like this:

<Configuration packages="biz.paluch.logging.gelf.log4j2,io.sentry.log4j2">
    <Appenders>
        <Gelf name="Gelf" host="tcp:graylog..." port="12000">
            <Field name="timestamp" pattern="%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS}"/>
        </Gelf>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="javax.net.ssl" level="TRACE">
            <AppenderRef ref="Gelf"/>
        </Logger>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>

Comment: @sge: add an `additivity="false"` attribute to the "javax.net.ssl" logger. With `additivity="true"` (the default), every message logged is also passed to the appenders from the parent logger.

Comment: thanks , additivity="false" fixed the duplicated log entries. But i still see only warning even if javax.net.ssl: TRACE is set as log level